# Python Django REST call returning object number instead of object name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Python, and I guess I'm serializing it incorrectly.

**This is the REST call result:**
[image]

> **authors/models.py:**

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False, null=False, related_name='book_author')
    contents = models.TextField('Contents', blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> **authors/views.py**

```
from authors.models import Book, Author
from authors.serializers import BookSerializer, AuthorSerializer
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics


class ListCreateBooks(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

class ListCreateAuthor(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
```

> **authors/serializers.py**

```
from authors.models import Book, Author
from rest_framework import serializers

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        book_author = 'name'
```

I'm new to Django, but I tried many things, in my views.py I've added another class called `AuthorSerializer` importing from a corresponding class I created in serializers, but then I realized that I have no clue how to add my `ListCreateAuthor` to:

```
 url(r'^api-auth/', ListCreateBooks.as_view(), name='list_books')
```

I've added another parameter with `ListCreateAuthor.as_view()` that gave me an immediate error (and which also didn't make much sense) Am I going the wrong way here and how can I solve this?

> **EDIT:**  @Abdulafaja gave a partial answer, which did solve the read, but now after checking a POST insert - it gives an error for create or update.

in [Django rest_framework's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) (link provided by @Abdulafaja) it give only one example for a nested serializer, and it's a one to many relationship (Album->tracks) but mine is one to one (book->author) so I have no idea how to serilize the nested feature. This API needs to give the frontend all CRUD features.

Thanks.

> **EDITED serializers.py by Abdullah:**

```
from authors.models import Book, Author
from rest_framework import serializers


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        book_author = 'name'


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            author, _ = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data.get('author').get('name'))
            return Book.objects.create(name=validated_data.get('name'), author=author)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            author = validated_data.get('author')
            if author:
                instance.author = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=author.get('name'))
            instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding you wish to get details of Authors in the api request not just their number??

The way to do that is to set the depth in your model serializer.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')
        depth=1
```

The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation. i.e. 1, 2, 3...

source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Hi Sarosh, we currently solved that part, since the API needs to be CRUD on the frontside, Abdulafaja is trying to help with the create() and update(), since it's nested. Please read the commentary. it's still not working so feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

For Book model Author is just an id of that field in database, so that's why it's return an integer field.
Try to add an Author field in Book serializer

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')
```

This is a NestedSerializer, which is read-only by default. On it's DRF doc site [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) is mentioned that you

> need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

So your BookSerializer needs to look like this

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Create new object

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Update existing instance
```

Both `create` and `update` methods need to save the object to the database and return it. There are called when you save your BookSerializer class instance.
The difference between them is that `create` is called when you create new instance of Book object

```
serializer = BookSerializer(data=data)
```

and `update` is called if you passed an existing instance of Book object when instantiating the serializer class

```
serializer = BookSerializer(book, data=data)
```

More information you can find [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

**EDIT:**
If you want to create an instance with NestedSerializer it should not be read only field.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author, _ = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data.get('author').get('name'))
        return Book.objects.create(name=validated_data.get('name'), author=author)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        author = validated_data.get('author')
        if author:
            instance.author = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=author.get('name'))
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: actually I checked with adding a new book through the django rest framework display and it provided this error that is directly connected to the author: http://prntscr.com/cd7wkf how can I solve this?

Comment: From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers: By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

Comment: Ok, understood, I have no idea where to begin this process. Can you be kind to add that process to your answer? I need to create a full CRUD for the frontside, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've read that in the link you provided and `def create(self, validated_data):` & `def update(self, instance, validated_data):` are totally understandable and written there, but since the relationship of the example documented link (one to many) and my model relationship (one to one) are different, the real question i'm asking is what goes in the `def` function where you wrote `# Create new object` and `# Update existing instance` I'll try to rummage that my self but if you can provide a quick solution, that would be appreciated.

Comment: excellent, but now the error is:   

name 'data' is not defined

Comment: hi, re your last edit: it states that "author=author_object" is an unresolved reference.

Comment: Sorry, mistake, I am going to fix it

Comment: np mate, there is no other area for accepting author name and  the run-error is:

Exception Value:  

null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (11, asdas, , null).

Comment: Hi, I checked the edit, but it still throws the error above and there is no place to add the author name, only bookname, even though I put read_only=False for AuthorSerializer.

Comment: Did you change anything in your `views.py` file? These which you posted in your question are well. read_only=False is a default value, you do not have to put it.

Comment: nope. authors/views.py  is the same and untouched. As you can see in this link: http://prntscr.com/cda11i -there is no field to insert author. And from this link: http://prntscr.com/cda1it -the error.

Comment: i'll post the new serializers.py with your edit. check the post above in a few sec.

Comment: You have wrong indentation for `create` and `update` functions. It should be at the same level as `class Meta:`

Comment: you're 100% right, I fixed it but still getting the error: http://prntscr.com/cda7fk

Comment: Any idea @Abdulafaja what is the issue of the error above?

Comment: No, I can not reproduce it